# Как уловить остановку курсора?

Tags: javascript

Друзья, мне необходимо сделать баннер, на котором при событии движения мыши (mousemove) двигаются некоторые объекты. Вся соль в том, что заказчику требуется, чтобы после остановки курсора объекты останавливались по инерции. Не понимаю, как реализовать такое. Единственной мыслью было использование функции с интервалом 1ms и проверять в ней dx / dy. Подскажите чего-нибудь, кто может. JQuery-плагины не желательны. Хотелось бы в самой механике самому разобраться. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: [Тут вроде неплохие решения](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066849/how-to-detect-if-mousemove-is-ended)

Тем более все равно по идее нужен сетИнтервал, так как для иннерции нужно понимать не только направление, но и скорость движения мыши.

Comment: Можно в терминах RxJS.  На вход подаёте поток событий "мышка подвигалась", фильтруете этот поток по геометрическим координатам, применяете к нему оператор debounce с требуемой задержкой и на выходе генерируете событие "мышка остановилась".